# Create a custom value Select Query in helper method in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i am trying to create a something like below, in my Laravel 5.1 project within helper.php.

`$result = App\Pages::where('id', $id)->where('active', 1)->first();`

here is how my **helper.php** looks like:

```
<?php
namespace App\Helpers;
use App;
class Helper
{
        public static function checkSlug($subject, $id, $inputSlug = null){
            $result = App\$subject::where('id', $id)->where('active', 1)->first();
            return $result;
        }
}
?>
```

My Helper class seems working fine. But i am stuck in this line `App\$subject::where('id', $id)->where('active', 1)->first();`. When i pass the variable `$subject` i get this below error:

```
parse error, expecting `"identifier (T_STRING)"'
```

And here is how i am using my helper method in my view

`{{Helper::checkSlug('Pages', $page->id)}}`

Now when i am trying to access my Model using `App\$subject` its not allow. I guess.

Any suggestions will be helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mean you can't use variable classes with static methode syntax. But you can instantiate your model:

```
public static function checkSlug($subject, $id, $inputSlug = null)
{
    $clsname = 'App\\' . $subject;
    $cls = new $clsname();
    $result = $cls->where('id', $id)->where('active', 1)->first();
    return $result;
}
```

and with the object build your query and get your row or not.

Comment: Thank you reply. But its showing `parse error` on `$cls=new {$clsname}();`

Comment: FatalErrorException in Helper.php line 14:
parse error

Comment: Okay, check this: <code>public static function checkSlug($subject, $id, $inputSlug = null)
    {
        $clsname = 'App\\' . $subject;
        $cls = new $clsname();
        $result = $cls->where('id', $id)->where('active', 1)->first();
        return $result;
    }</code>